# Unable to install Ubuntu on an iMac

Tags: installation

I download the install .iso from the ubuntu download site, no problems. I burn the ISO to a DVD medium as a disc image on my windows computer, no problem. I take that DVD over to my imac, and it won't read the disc.

The iMac is running OSX now, I want Ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have the correct cpu architecture. It may need a PPC arch (Power PC)
If not 64-bit should work.